# Cannot GROUP BY or DISTINCT my QUERY for xml path

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, for-xml-path, caspio

I'm pulling Chapter Titles, Section Titles, and Questions from my tables to make a table of contents. I am using Caspio's low code platform, which runs on SQL-Server.

I've been able to GROUP BY or ORDER BY, but I can't seem to do both. For my purposes, ORDER BY is way more important. GROUP BY will just make it easier to handle. When I add a GROUP BY statement it shows nothing.

I want to be able to GROUP BY or use DISTINCT, do you see any reason why cannot?

Here is my query:

```
SELECT [@field:WF_tbl_Chapter_Title] as Chapter, [@field:WF_tbl_Section_Title] as Section, [@field:WF_tbl_Question_Description] as Question
FROM _v_Questions_View as QV
WHERE [@field:WF_tbl_Workbook_Author_ID] = '[@authfield:WF_tbl_Customer_Customer_ID]' 
AND [@field:WF_tbl_Workbook_Workbook_ID] = '[@WID] '
ORDER BY QV.WF_tbl_Chapter_Position, QV.WF_tbl_Section_Position, QV.WF_tbl_Question_Position

for xml path(N'')
```

Here is an example of a query that fails to show anything:

```
SELECT [@field:WF_tbl_Chapter_Title] as Chapter, [@field:WF_tbl_Section_Title] as Section, [@field:WF_tbl_Question_Description] as Question
FROM _v_Questions_View as QV
WHERE [@field:WF_tbl_Workbook_Author_ID] = '[@authfield:WF_tbl_Customer_Customer_ID]' 
AND [@field:WF_tbl_Workbook_Workbook_ID] = '[@WID]'
GROUP BY [@field:WF_tbl_Chapter_Title], [@field:WF_tbl_Section_Title], [@field:WF_tbl_Question_Description]
ORDER BY QV.WF_tbl_Chapter_Position, QV.WF_tbl_Section_Position, QV.WF_tbl_Question_Position
for xml path(N'')
```

Comment: For group by do you include all three fields, and not the aliases, like:  group by [@field:WF_tbl_Chapter_Title] , [@field:WF_tbl_Section_Title], [@field:WF_tbl_Question_Description].  In what you do show, in the select,

Comment: I have tried it grouping by all 3 or by just grouping on [@field:WF_tbl_Chapter_Title]. I have also tried putting DISTINCT in front of each in the SELECT statement. I have tried using their proper names and their aliases.

Comment: If you use distinct only use it once, in the select:  "SELECT DISTINCT A, B, C".   It is fine to use column aliases with DISTINCT.    If you use GROUP BY, that goes after the from clause and DBs I'm familiar with need the real names, not aliases you defined:  SELECT A, B, C from T WHERE... GROUP BY A, B, C ORDER BY A, B" for example. ORDER BY has to come after GROUP BY if you use it.   Best if you can edit your post to show text of a query that fails.

Comment: I added a failing query. When I SELECT DISTINCT A, B, C - it throws and error. When I SELECT DISTINCT A, DISTINCT B, DISTINCT C - it runs but returns nothing. I have checked again with ORDER BY in the proper spot - it returns nothing.

Comment: for group by, you have to include all the columns in the SELECT list.   The first form you show of distinct is correct in standard sql -- the second one SHOULD give an error.

Comment: It's the other way around, and I can't see the error messages (using a low code platform that obscures all that) to help explain it. I have added all the columns from the SELECT criteria to the GROUP BY - still nothing. 

When I added GROUP BY [@field:WF_tbl_Chapter_Title], [@field:WF_tbl_Section_Title], [@field:WF_tbl_Question_Description] it threw an error.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product (and your query is invalid standard SQL). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: I added sql-server tag, thank you for the advice. SQL-Server is sitting underneath the Caspio Bridge - a low code platform, which was tagged.

Comment: `WHERE [@field:WF_tbl_Workbook_Author_ID] = '[@authfield:WF_tbl_Customer_Customer_ID]' AND [@field:WF_tbl_Workbook_Workbook_ID] = '[@WID]'` probably doesn't do what you think it does. Those apostrophes mean that they have to equal that piece of text. And your failing query is group by the wrong column , you selected `WF_tbl_Question_Description` but are grouping by `WF_tbl_Question_Position`

Comment: @Charlieface the Caspio bridge renders all those fields into their values. The WHERE clause works. I get the values I'm looking for. Thank you for catching the mistype - I edited it above, unfortunately that doesn't resolve my issue, I simply mistyped it in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search Stack Overflow for questions about  distinct with "for xml" in sql server. Caspio uses sql server.

Answers commonlly advise isolating the initial select in a subquery or CTE.

So a guess.... wrap your working query like one of these:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Chapter, Section, Question FROM
(SELECT [@field:WF_tbl_Chapter_Title] as Chapter, [@field:WF_tbl_Section_Title] as Section, [@field:WF_tbl_Question_Description] as Question
 FROM _v_Questions_View as QV
 WHERE [@field:WF_tbl_Workbook_Author_ID] = '[@authfield:WF_tbl_Customer_Customer_ID]' 
 AND [@field:WF_tbl_Workbook_Workbook_ID] = '[@WID] '
 ) AS SUBQ
 ORDER BY Chapter, Section, Question
for xml path(N'')
```

or

```
WITH X AS
    (SELECT [@field:WF_tbl_Chapter_Title] as Chapter, [@field:WF_tbl_Section_Title] as Section, [@field:WF_tbl_Question_Description] as Question
     FROM _v_Questions_View as QV
     WHERE [@field:WF_tbl_Workbook_Author_ID] = '[@authfield:WF_tbl_Customer_Customer_ID]' 
     AND [@field:WF_tbl_Workbook_Workbook_ID] = '[@WID] '
     GROUP BY [@field:WF_tbl_Chapter_Title], [@field:WF_tbl_Section_Title], [@field:WF_tbl_Question_Description]
     )
SELECT Chapter, Section, Question
FROM X
ORDER BY  Chapter, Section, Question
for xml path(N'')
```

Comment: That is helpful. Those code examples didn't do the trick, but you've helped me think about the problem in a new way. I appreciate your efforts, thank you.